# Text property of ListItem that created dynamically

Tags: asp.net, listitem

I create many ListItem dynamically for a DropDownList ASP.net control, and need some of this ListItem's Text Property, have two or three "Space". I try this:

```
var li = new ListItem { Text = "&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;" + "Item" };
```

but in HTML rendered page, it's text appears ==> `'&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;Item'`

What should I do?

Comment: Do you actually want to add the same space at the left side? Then use CSS instead: `li.CssStyle.Add("margin-left:5px;")`.

Comment: I need li Text property, for example be '---item'.
'-'s are 'space'.

Comment: Thanks "Tim", but using margin-left for select items, don't works in some browsers.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try to decode the space characters first...

```
li.Text = HttpUtility.HtmlDecode("&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;") + "Item";
```